# Nest JS - Can't exclude route from middleware

Tags: node.js, routes, swagger, nestjs

I use basic authentication for my NestJS API. I also have page with route `/api/docs` where I generate documentation using SwaggerUI. What I want to do is I want to exclude this route, so you can get access to this page without credentials.

The issue is that even though I excluded this route, I still can't get access to this route.

Middleware:

```js
import type { NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import type { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

import { ApiConfigService } from '@shared/config.service';

@Injectable()
export class BasicAuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private configService: ApiConfigService) {}

  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    if (req.headers['authorization']) {
      const authorization = req.headers['authorization'];
      const basic = authorization.match(/^Basic (.+)$/);

      if (!basic) return new UnauthorizedException();

      const credentials = Buffer.from(basic[1], 'base64').toString('utf-8');

      const apiUsername = this.configService.basicAuthConfig.username;
      const apiPassword = this.configService.basicAuthConfig.password;

      if (credentials != `${apiUsername}:${apiPassword}`) {
        return new UnauthorizedException();
      }

      return next();
    }
    return new UnauthorizedException();
  }
}
```

AppModule:

```js
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(BasicAuthMiddleware)
      .exclude('/api/docs')
      .forRoutes({
        path: '*',
        method: RequestMethod.ALL
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [Global prefix](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix#global-prefix) to `main.ts` and pass empty string prefix parameter if don't prefix it

main.ts:

```js
app.setGlobalPrefix('', {
  exclude: [{ path: '/api/docs', method: RequestMethod.ALL }],
});
```

> Note: Don't forget cors origin